# whether nonce increases if tx is invalid due to invalid sig

Tags: transactions, signature, nonce

I am wondering that whether nonce increases if tx is invalid due to invalid sig.
Based on what I know, the nonce increases even though tx is invalid regarding of the reason of failure. right?
If so, it seems possible that someone can increase my account's nonce by sending any tx with invalid sig so that prevent my txs from mining. I thing this is pretty big issue for someone..

Please correct me.

Answer (score 0):

An account nonce starts at 0. The nonce goes up by 1 if the transaction is an outgoing transaction, whatsoever the transaction succeeds or fails.
Incoming transaction do not change the nonce of the receiver.